# Python3.x Prime Number List with while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

```
def prime(upper):
    while upper >=2:
        for num in range(2, upper + 1):
            prime = True
            for i in range(2, num):
                if (num % i == 0):
                    prime = False
            if prime:
                print(num, end=",")
                if num == upper:   #I think there is a problem here
                   break
prime(7)
```

How can I stop this function when it reachs 7 value
PS: I want to execute this codes with while loop.
BTW if you can make it this codes without for-loop please do it for me :)
I appreciate you...

Comment: Refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664067/python-while-loop-for-finding-prime-numbers

Comment: Delete `while upper >=2:`, it is unnecessary. `for num in range(2, upper + 1):` is doing the job.

Comment: Also, `if num == upper:break` part is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I guess my previous `is_prime` function is problematic. This way is quicker and works well:([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285590/6900838))

```
def is_prime(n):
    """"pre-condition: n is a nonnegative integer
    post-condition: return True if n is prime and False otherwise."""
    if n < 2: 
         return False;
    if n % 2 == 0:             
         return n == 2  # return False
    k = 3
    while k*k <= n:
         if n % k == 0:
             return False
         k += 2
    return True
```

You should use this function.

**BEFORE EDIT:**

I would use the `is_prime` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32882220/6900838). You can use another way.

And, I would suggest this code for you:

```
def is_prime(Number):
    return 2 in [Number, 2**Number%Number]

def prime(upper):
    print([num for num in range(2, upper + 1) if is_prime(num)])

prime(7)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

But if you insist on using only `while` loop, you can modify your `prime` function as:

```
def prime(upper):
    num = 2
    while num <= upper:
        if is_prime(num):
            print(num, end = ",")
        num += 1
```

Then, output will be:

```
2,3,5,7,
```

Comment: its kind of help me but can I ask that what is the purpose of this code 

**return 2 in [Number, 2**Number%Number]**

Comment: It is just a function I found on the internet. I don't know its logic. There are other functions in the link given in the answer.

Comment: If you can't find the link, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language/32882220#32882220). I gues, this way is a little problematic, there are poor comments in the link. I chose it because it is short. You can use another `is_prime` function.

Comment: @TwisterJoe I edited my answer. You can use the new `is_prime` function.